# Differentiating between two View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, crash, segue

I have 3 VC. A which displays questions and answers. B is displayed when the Question is wrongly selected a C once the level is clear.
I am having an issue going from A-B & A-C.
Here is my code

```
#import "AViewController.h"
#import "BViewController.h"
#import "CViewController.h"

@interface AViewController ()
@end
```

Now here is the implementation code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
BViewController *incorrect = [segue destinationViewController];
incorrect.currentQuestion = self.currentQuestion;}
```

//Here A is sending B information about which question was answered incorrectly i.e Current Question

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Addition1" ofType:@"plist"]];
currentQuestion = -1;
[self showNextQuestion];

}

 -(void) showNextQuestion{
currentQuestion++;
if (currentQuestion <= 3) {

    int numItems = [rootArray count];
    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *addimage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *Answer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];


    for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
        [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
        [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
        [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
        [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];
        [addimage addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"ImageUse"]];
        [Answer addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"ANS"]];

    }
    self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];
    self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
    self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
    self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];
    additionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:addimage[currentQuestion]];
    self.correctAns = Answer[currentQuestion];}
else{
    NSLog(@"End of Array ");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"levelpassed" sender:nil];

}
}
```

This area above here is where I am having the problem

When the the level is cleared C VC is having this error displaying

```
[CViewController setCurrentQuestion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71cae70
2013-03-30 21:17:31.264 thefyp[14311:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception         'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CViewController setCurrentQuestion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71cae70'
```

I know the issue is that A is finding it hard to differentiate between segue and is trying to send C data about current question when all I want to do is display C when the A is finished showing all questions and no data is being transferred like when A is segueing to B. B & C also is a subclass of A. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please check if you have changed the identity of viewController in storyboard.

Comment: Of the segue identifier?

Comment: Identity of the CViewController

Answer (score 1):

In the `prepareForSegue` method check the segue identifier `UIStoryboardSegue.identifier` whether it matches the transition to your `B`-VC.

Because calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:@"levelPassed"` will also run into this method and there you do not have a `B`-VC and therefore no `currentQuestion`.

Comment: That seems to have worked. The only issue is now the current Question is not updating at all in the B VC which is means the current question is not being updated here is the code for the prepareForSegue
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"level1correct"]){
    AddLevel1IncorrectViewController *incorrect = [segue destinationViewController];
        incorrect.currentQuestion = self.currentQuestion;}
}`

Comment: I don't get the main problem: the `currentQuestion` in your `AddLevel1IncorrectViewController` is not set when it is displayed?

Comment: The B view controller is pushed when a question is answered incorrectly in A. A passes on the value of current question to B so  B can display information about the question all depending on the current Question value. Does that makes sense?